# Facebook ios sdk login from UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-login

I am building an app that has a navigationitem in the navigation bar.

I am trying to understand how to use the facebook sdk to connect to facebook (authenticating) when the button is clicked.

This is not some special viewcontroller or something.

I have seen this: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

but in there i need to create some things in the delegate (like a UINavigationController) that i can't use because i am using a UITabBarController..

how can i implement facebook login and session creation just from pushing the UINavigationItem?

**Here is my AppDelegate.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tbc;

@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;


@end
```

**And my AppDelegate.m:**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "StatusView.h"
#import "JokesView.h"
#import "HomeView.h"
#import "TopTenView.h"
#import "UploadView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize tbc;
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize session = _session;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UINavigationController*nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController*nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController*nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController*nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController*nav5 = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

    StatusView*page1 = [[StatusView alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusView" bundle:nil];
    JokesView*page2 = [[JokesView alloc]initWithNibName:@"JokesView" bundle:nil];
    HomeView*page3 = [[HomeView alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
    TopTenView*page4 = [[TopTenView alloc]initWithNibName:@"TopTenView" bundle:nil];
    UploadView*page5 = [[UploadView alloc]initWithNibName:@"UploadView" bundle:nil];

    page1.title = @"סטטוסים";
    page2.title = @"תמונות";
    page3.title = @"ראשי";
    page4.title = @"Top 10";
    page5.title = @"העלאה";

    UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status"
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tbc-status.png"] tag:1];
    [nav1 setTabBarItem:tab1];

    UITabBarItem *tab2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Jokes"
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tbc-jokes.png"] tag:1];
    [nav2 setTabBarItem:tab2];

    UITabBarItem *tab3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tbc-home.png"] tag:1];
    [nav3 setTabBarItem:tab3];

    UITabBarItem *tab4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tpp10"
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tbc-topten.png"] tag:1];
    [nav4 setTabBarItem:tab4];

    UITabBarItem *tab5 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload"
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tbc-upload.png"] tag:1];
    [nav5 setTabBarItem:tab5];


    [nav1 pushViewController:page1 animated:NO];
    [nav2 pushViewController:page2 animated:NO];
    [nav3 pushViewController:page3 animated:NO];
    [nav4 pushViewController:page4 animated:NO];
    [nav5 pushViewController:page5 animated:NO];

    tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav5,nav4,nav3,nav2,nav1, nil];
    tbc.selectedIndex = 2;

    // NavBar Design
    UIImage *navbarPortrait = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.jpg"]
                               resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *navbarLandscape = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.jpg"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarPortrait
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarLandscape
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    // NavBar Design End

    // TabBar Design
    UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tbcb3ack.png"]
                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
    [[tbc tabBar] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
    // TabBar Design End

    [self.window addSubview:tbc.view];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tbc;

    // Push Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)];
    // Push Notifications End

    // Facebook Code Start

    //UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not Logged in"
    //                                                message:@"You Log in to use all the fearues in this app"
    //                                               delegate:nil
    //                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
    //                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // To-do, show logged in view
    } else {
        //[alert show];

    }

    // Facebook Code End

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}

// Facebook sdk code Start

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:self.session];
}

// Facebook sdk code End

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:self.session];
}
#pragma mark Template generated code

@end
```

These are after i used the facebook ios authentication tutorial, before the actual fb session changes and login button.

Comment: what you have tried? Can you post some code?

Comment: i tried just that one and some old tutorial... i have no current code because it just didn't work out as i am trying no to use the login as a full viewcontroller but as a function of anyviewcontroller i have/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really are two parts to solving this problem.  You first need to define a UIButton to be a UINavigationItem which will do your login (or log out) on click.  And second, your app has to be ready to accept the login event.  I'm not sure which part is causing you more trouble, but here's how you set up part one, the button:

```
UIButton *loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 75.0f, 44.0f);
[loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton addEventHandler:^(id sender)
{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
                                       ^(FBSession *session, 
                                         FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                  [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];
}
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:loginButton];
```

As for part two, you need to define the sessionStateChanged function in this view controller.  To save you trouble, here's the general structure that you need for the sessionStateChanged method:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session 
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // Connected to facebook... so go to your next view controller
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // Login failed
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle:@"Error"
                           message:error.localizedDescription
                          delegate:nil
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }    
}
```

You'll also need to implement a lot of other things, especially in your app delegate.  I'm happy to write out more code samples for you, but help me understand what you want to see next.

## UPDATE

Ok, so now that I understand you want to have this facebook button stay with you on the nav bar, I would subclass the nav controller, set the subclasss to be its own delegate, and add the facebook button to each view controller that's added.  The thing to note is, the navigation bar that's drawn uses the navigationItem of each view controller that's added to the navigation controller.  So technically, you need to add this same button to every view controller that's pushed or popped in and out of the navigation controller.  Instead of copy-pasting code around or even setting up a utility class (or super class) that all your view controllers use to insert this facebook button, a quick and dirty way is to create a single button in a navigation controller subclass and insert that same button as each view controller is shown.  So here's a very bare bones version of what the navigation controller subclass might look like this in its implementation file:

```
@interface MYNavigationController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong)           UIButton *facebookButton;
@end

@implementation MYNavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set this subclass as its own delegate to be able receive the willShowViewController: method
    self.delegate                       = self;

    // Create a shared facebook button
    _facebookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _facebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 75.0f, 44.0f);
    [_facebookButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_facebookButton
        addTarget:self
        action:@selector(onFacebookButtonClick:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // As each view controller is about to be shown, change the view controller's
    // navigationItem to have this facebook button as its right bar button
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.facebookButton];
}

- (void)onFacebookButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    // Handle the click event when the facebook button is clicked
    // You need to have logic here to know if the session is open or not
    // Of course, when the session isn't open, then open a new session (ie. login)
    // and when the session IS open, then close the session (ie. logout)
    [FBSession
        openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
        allowLoginUI:YES
        completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
        {
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
        }];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // Connected to facebook so...
            // 1. change the button text to say "logout" instead of "login"
            // 2. go to your next view controller
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // Login failed so revert everything to pre-login state
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

And then, simply use this MYNavigationController as your navigation controller class.  Don't forget to go through the [facebook ios authentication tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) for a guided tour of how to set up your app (there's plenty of frameworks to add, infoplist changes, etc).

Happy to help more if you need it!

## Update #2

Because your window's root view controller is a `UITabBarController`, then we can use that as the owner of the `facebookButton`, which is shared between all `UINavigationControllers`.  At a high level, the logic hasn't changed from my previous code sample.  You're creating a single button somewhere, that's being added to every view controller that's shown by your navigation controllers.  In order to do this, you need to first create a `UITabBarController` subclass (again, mine is called `MYTabBarController`, but you can call it whatever you want).  And it will look something like this in `MYTabBarController.m`:

```
#import "MYTabBarController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@implementation MYTabBarController

- (UIButton *)facebookButton
{
    if (! _facebookButton)
    {
        // Create a shared facebook button on demand
        _facebookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _facebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 75.0f, 44.0f);
        [_facebookButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_facebookButton
            addTarget:self
            action:@selector(onFacebookButtonClick:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return _facebookButton;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // As each view controller is about to be shown, change the view controller's
    // navigationItem to have this facebook button as its right bar button
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.facebookButton];
}

- (void)onFacebookButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    // Handle the click event when the facebook button is clicked
    // You need to have logic here to know if the session is open or not
    // Of course, when the session isn't open, then open a new session (ie. login)
    // and when the session IS open, then close the session (ie. logout)
    [FBSession
        openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
        allowLoginUI:YES
        completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
        {
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
        }];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // Connected to facebook so...
            // 1. change the button text to say "logout" instead of "login"
            //      eg. [self.facebookButton setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            // 2. go to your next view controller
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // Login failed so revert everything to pre-login state
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

The corresponding `MYTabBarController.h` will need to have at least a button defined and the fact it conforms to the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MYTabBarController: UITabBarController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong)           UIButton *facebookButton;
```

Finally, your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` needs to make a small change.  It needs to declare the tab bar as the delegate for each of your UINavigationControllers:

```
// Set the navigation controller delegates to be the tabbar in order to hook into the willShowViewController: method
nav1.delegate                       = tbc;
nav2.delegate                       = tbc;
nav3.delegate                       = tbc;
nav4.delegate                       = tbc;
nav5.delegate                       = tbc;
```

That should do it.  Hopefully you can take it from here.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the awesome comment! which files do i need to import for this? and do i need the session function on every page? i wan't the app to remember the user trhow all of it's pages. thanks :)

Comment: Ahh, I'm starting to see what you need.  So you actually want the login/logout button to stay with the navigation controller regardless which view controller is showing right?  If that's the case, then you need to subclass the UINavigationController, add this as part of your subclass, and handle all facebook logic in the nav controller.  If this is the case, just tell me, and I can edit my answer to be more specific.

Comment: yes this is it! i will be happy if you could show me how to do it :)

Comment: wow, amazing answer !! 
thank you very much :) 
about the update: i need to create a MYNavigationController.m file and than import it to every viewcontroller i have? and than inside the viewdidload do something like `self.navigationitem.leftbarbuttonitem = facebookButton;` ?

Comment: Not exactly. I call the UINavigationController subclass MYNavigationController, but you can call it whatever you want. This navigation controller (NC) will be the root view controller (VC) in your app. Then you can push and pop VCs to this NC just as you would any vanilla (non-subclassed) NC. You don't need to do anything inside of the VCs as this NC subclass will take care of adding the bar button. So in summary, create your project, make your root view a navigation controller (you can do this in storyboard), set its class to your NC subclass, start adding your VCs to this NC like normal.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it tommorrow and let you know :) the thing i think i would have a problem with is that i have a tabbar in my delegate that inside picks which .xib file will be first to load.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem unless you want each tab bar's tabs to have the same facebook button on the navigation bar. If it's only on a single navigation bar, then the nested structure of your app would be: app window > tab bar > navigation controllers (multiple, with one as your navigation controller subclass) > view controllers (pushed and popped into your navigation controller).

Comment: Yes... The tab bar is the pages and every one of them need to have the button in the nav bar.

Comment: Alright... help me understand the structure of your application.  When you first load the application, is the root view controller of your main window a UITabBar or a UINavigationController?  In other words, do you have a UITabBar nested inside a UINavigationController, or the other way around?  Also, when you say every one of them needs to have the button, are you referring to every view controller, or every tab in your tab bar?

Comment: my app works like this: i have a delegate which has a proprety of uitabbarcontroller. in the delegate.m , inside the "didFunishLaunchingWithOptions" i am calling all my viewcontrollers and than do: tabbarcontroller.viewcontrollers = array of the VCs. and than i select the index and thats the view controller my app launches first. i will now add my appdelegate.h and appdelegate.m to the main question.

Comment: hey, i don't really have a root viewcontroller.... in my delegate i have a function thant builds the UITabBarController and than i chose the index of it and this becomes the view... so i don't have something like "MYTabBarController" as i see in your answer what i would need to do is add the functions you put in the "MYTabBarController" into every viewcontroller i have that i wan't that button in, and than change what i have in my delegate?! i kind of lost you somewhere there..

Comment: Well, instead of using the vanilla UITabBarController, you want to use a subclass of UITabBarController that you create.  I happen to call my subclass MYTabBarController, but you can call it whatever you want.  In the end, the purpose of this specialized subclass is to hold onto this facebook button that you're sharing across all the tabs of your UITabBar.  Does that make sense?

Comment: my problem is that i don't have a "UITabBarController" as a page (.m/.h), what i use as my UITabBarController is decleard in the appDelegate.m

Comment: I am trying to understand where to put your code... can you be more specific?

Comment: You need to make a UITabBarController subclass.  Go to XCode, File > New > File, select Objective-C class, name it what you want but make sure it's a subclass of UITabBarController.  Then put the code in there.  Inside your __AppDelegate.m, add a #include "<insert name of new UITabBarController>.h" at the top, and instantiate an instance of your new class instead of the generic UITabBarController.

Comment: and than do something like: `self.window.rootViewController = MyTbc;` ?

Comment: i made it end everytime i press the button i get an error: `2013-07-04 20:46:37.890 Delike[24650:907] -[__NSCFType onFacebookButtonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c557130`

Comment: can i send you the app files and you will fix it?

Comment: hmm, that would be robbing you of a great chance to learn how all this stuff works.  I'm happy to continue this in chat and help you work through some of the bugs, but you should be the one driving.  Jump in this chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32905/discussing-facebook-ios-sdk-login-from-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

When you push to a viewController,  you should alloc viewControler before. And you can implement facebook login and session creation in alloc function of viewController.

Comment: i don't want to implant in a new viewcontroller but to use is as a function in an exsiting one... is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

That's posible. You can create facebook login and session in appDelegate. When you need show facebook view, you can call a function to popup facebook view.

Comment: can you give me a code example? and i don't want any popup, i want it to move to the facebook app for the validation and come back.